# How to get Azure Availability Zone provided region while creating Virtual Machine using .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-management-api

I am trying to get Availability Zone provided the region information using .NET SDK but I am not able to get the exact same information which I can see on Azure while creating virtual machine from portal.

Following call returning me huge list of array where most of the entries are empty but few of them having [1 2 3]. Moreover, it takes alot of time.( around 10-12 seconds to bring the data )

```
        var connection = GetAzConnection(subscriptionId);
        List<string> ZoneInfo = new List<string>();
        var skus = connection.ComputeSkus.ListbyRegionAndResourceType(Region.Create(regionName),ComputeResourceType.VirtualMachines);
        foreach (IComputeSku sku in skus)
        {                
            var regionZones = sku.Zones;
            ZoneInfo.Add(RegionZoneToString(regionZones));
        }
```

While I am expecting just [ 1 2 3 ] against 'WesternEurope'  for example.

Any idea how to get that corresponding info?

For reference, following code snippet.

[image]

Few regions where there are no zones information can be collected.

[image]

Comment: I assume you want the information which zone a particular VM is deployed in?! I dont know the .NET SDK well, but your query does not seem to do that. Instead it queries something around SKUs

Comment: NO I want to create a VM by selecting a zone ( e.g. Zone 1, Zone2, Zone 3 ) from a combo box.
and showing Zone 1, Zone2 , Zone3 , I have to provide the region first and then it should return me the Zone 1, Zone2 and Zone3. Like in azure portal.

Comment: Basically This is mandatory field in ARM Template. We need to provide Zone information while creating virtual machine using ARM Template.

Comment: I dont quite understand the use case. At least up to now (as far as I am aware), each region which has zones, has exactly 1,2 and 3. Maybe more might be coming but I think the three are always there

Comment: you can see there are few regions, where there are no zone information at all. I edited the post with the pic.

Comment: So I can't blindly show 1,2 and 3 . Might be the provided region has entirely no zone information at all.

Comment: yes, not every region has AZs. But those which do, will have at least 3.

Comment: SO, then how to query which regions have zones? Because I need to update this info on GUI. If there are no zones per region then I'll not put any info otherwise 1,2,3